# Powerpoint 2013 display differently in OSX and Window version

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

It is the original slide in Powerpoint for Mac 2011
[image: osx]

And it is how it looks in Powerpoint 2013 on Windows

[image: win]

Here is the version information of my Powerpoint for Mac

[image]

I have googled this problem but fail to find a solution.

How can I fix this incompatibility?

**EDIT**

If you want to see the file, [download it here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/239oay4ekr2vil2/Thank%20you.pptx?dl=0)

Comment: Put the file on OneDrive/Dropbox or someplace else where others can download it to have a look.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Here is a link https://www.dropbox.com/s/239oay4ekr2vil2/Thank%20you.pptx?dl=0 Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting the file. I see the same thing here. It looks to me as if the shape (rectangle) with the text is corrupt. The shape still contains the text, but if you attempt to change the text color, it shrinks down to 0 height. If this is just happening to the one slide and doesn't repeat itself with new slides, I'd delete the slide, re-create it and move along.  It's not typical of what happens between PPT Mac and Windows.